# sum(amount) from three tables returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having following tables

```
create table supplier_paid_details(
    id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    payment_mode varchar(20),
    payment_date date,
    add_date timestamp DEFAULT 0,
    status varchar(20),
    supp_payment_id bigint(10) NOT NULL,
    primary Key(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_paid FOREIGN KEY (supp_payment_id)
    REFERENCES supplier_payment_details(id)
    );

create table supplier_paid_check(
id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
check_no bigint(10) NOT NULL, 
dated date,
payable_at varchar(50),
paid_to_acc_no varchar(30),
paid_to_bank varchar(30),
paid_to_branch varchar(30),
spd_id bigint(10),
add_date timestamp DEFAULT 0,
amount float(10,2),
status varchar(20),
primary Key(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_ckeck FOREIGN KEY (spd_id)
REFERENCES supplier_payment_details(id)
);



create table supplier_paid_online(
id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pay_ref_no varchar(50),
paid_from_bank varchar(50),
from_acc_no varchar(50),
paid_to_acc_no varchar(30),
paid_to_bank varchar(30),
paid_to_branch varchar(30),
spd_id bigint(10),
add_date timestamp DEFAULT 0,
amount float(10,2),
status varchar(20),
primary Key(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_online FOREIGN KEY (spd_id)
REFERENCES supplier_paid_details(id)
);

create table supplier_paid_cash(
id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
to_person varchar(40),
designation varchar(40),
receipt_no varchar(30),
spd_id bigint(10),
add_date timestamp DEFAULT 0,
amount float(10,2),
status varchar(20),
primary Key(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_cash FOREIGN KEY (spd_id)
REFERENCES supplier_paid_details(id)
);
```

Here I would like to sum amounts from `supplier_paid_check`,`supplier_paid_cash`,`supplier_paid_online`.

for that I am using following query but this is showing null.

```
 select sum(ca.amount+ch.amount+onl.amount) as amount from
supplier_paid_details as pd
left join supplier_paid_cash as ca
on pd.id=ca.spd_id
left join supplier_paid_check as ch
on pd.id=ch.spd_id
left join supplier_paid_online as onl
on pd.id=onl.spd_id
where pd.supp_payment_id=1;
```

Comment: Hard to say without actually seeing the data. If `sum` returns `null` it means there are no rows returned. Did you try to run the query to see if it returns any rows using that `where`?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that anything to do with money would be FLOAT! See DECIMAL. And try using SUM(COALESCE(column_a,0)+COALESCE(...

Comment: I have one very important question: Is `spd_id` **UNIQUE** in each of the child tables?  Or can you have multiple instances of payments per `detail` row?

Comment: NO `spd_id` id is not unique. If you have to pay 200000 in installments in 1 year. you can pay cash any number of time also chechs and online many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(
              coalesce(ca.amount, 0)
            + coalesce(ch.amount, 0)
            + coalesce(onl.amount, 0)
          ) as amount from
....
```

or this:

```
select sum(ca.amount) + sum(ch.amount) + sum(onl.amount) as amount from
....
```

Comment: Same returning null there are values in all tables

Comment: Does it return any rows when you select * ...?

Comment: Yes Second query is working when I removed `where pd.supp_payment_id=1;`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is at least one row in one of your three tables where `amount` has a `NULL` value. This leads to `NULL` as result in the end as the DBMS could not determine how to handle this value in combination with the other. But there is a way out: you could tell your DBMS what to do with `NULL` values. Use `IFNULL`.

```
select
    sum(IFNULL(ca.amount, 0) + IFNULL(ch.amount, 0) + IFNULL(onl.amount, 0)) as amount 
from
    supplier_paid_details as pd left join supplier_paid_cash as ca on pd.id=ca.spd_id
    left join supplier_paid_check as ch on pd.id=ch.spd_id
    left join supplier_paid_online as onl on pd.id=onl.spd_id
where
    pd.supp_payment_id=1;
```

Read more on `IFNULL` at [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: +--------+
| amount |
+--------+
|   NULL |
+--------+

Comment: This query is also working perfectly when i removed `pd.supp_payment_id=1;`